# Display ResultSet in Table View

Tags: android, mysql, tablelayout

I really need help
I have a ResultSet as a result of select query from MySQL DB. how can I display it in table layout?? I have setup a layout for tableview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myFilter"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/some_hint" />
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="10dp"
  android:text="@string/some_text" android:textSize="20sp" />
<TableLayout
 android:id="@+id/producttablelayout"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:dividerPadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"
 android:showDividers="none|beginning|middle|end" >

 <TableRow
     android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="top|bottom|left|right"
     android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/ttt1"
         android:text="Column 1"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/ttt2"
         android:text="Column 12"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


 </TableRow>

 </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to be able to add ResultSet data into it. Something like:

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     String s = null;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_all_products);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    context333=this;
    TableLayout myTable = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.producttablelayout);
    try
    {
    connect2 = DriverManager.getConnection(LogonActivity.url, LogonActivity.user, LogonActivity.password);
    statement2 = connect2.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, 
            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    preparedStatement2 = connect2.prepareStatement("select     article_code,article_desc from products limit 4");
    resultSet2=preparedStatement2.executeQuery();
   resultSet2.beforeFirst();

   while (resultSet2.next()) {
      how to add next record here to the table layout??

   }
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new Views (it seems you are populating your table rows with TextViews) and populate them with the results from your query as you wish. Then you can create a new `TableRow` with a constructor ([see the documentation](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_TableLayout_and_TableRow_Tutorial)).

Add the views to to table row instnace using:

`tableRowInstance.addView(viewInstance);`

and then add the `tableRow` to the `tableLayout` the same way:

`myTable.addView(tableRowInstance)`

TableLayouts and TableRows are both subclasses of View. You should do some research on `ViewGroup`, View, and how they are structured. [This link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_TableLayout_and_TableRow_Tutorial) provides nice visualizations.

Comment: what I have now is as follows:`code`while (resultSet2.next()) {  
     TextView text111 = new TextView(this);
 text111.setText(String.valueOf(resultSet2.getString("article_code")));   TextView text222 = new TextView(this);   text222.setText(String.valueOf(resultSet2.getString("article_desc")));TableRow tableRowInstance = new TableRow(this);for(int i=1;i<3;i++){TextView text=new TextView(this);text.setText(String.valueOf(resultSet2.getString(i))); tableRowInstance.addView(text);}myTable.addView(tableRowInstance);
HOW can I pre define layout of the row? in XML?

Comment: @Alex, it is hard to read code that is in the comment section. If my answer sufficiently solved your original question, please except it and post the above code as a new question. This is beneficial to you and the SO community as everyone has an opportunity to answer your next question and people that may have the same issue can search for it efficiently. Thank you

Comment: Thanks Scott. it did. Will post another one as a new question